# Multiple ElasticSearch filters in Grails

Tags: grails, filter, elasticsearch, nested

I have the following query in Grails (Plugin elasticsearch:0.0.3.8) which works perfect:

```
class MyDomain {

 User user
 String text
 Boolean deleted
 Boolean disabled

 static searchable = { user component:true }

}

class User {
    String name
    static searchable = { root false }
}

MyDomain.search(searchType: 'dfs_query_and_fetch') {
        query_string(query: params.query, fields:['text'])
    } {
        nested {
            path = "user"
            query {
                bool {
                    must { match("user.name": params.name) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But now I wanna add some additional filters :
match("deleted": true)
match("disabled": true)

Can somebody explain to me how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: wrap the nested part on its own in a `bool.must` block and add your other matchers there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Many thanks to cfrick for his help.

```
MyDomain.search(searchType: 'dfs_query_and_fetch') {
        query_string(query: params.query, fields:['text'])
    } {
        bool {
            must { term(disabled: true) }
            must { term(deleted: true) }
            must {
                nested {
                    path = "user"
                    query {
                        bool {
                            must { match("user.name": params.name) }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```